# Holding multiple axes' plots in Matlab GUI:

Tags: matlab, user-interface, plot

I'm currently developing a GUI (programatically. No GUIDE has been used) for a project and I need to place 11 axes on the same GUI. I'm using the axes command to get the handles of the 11 controls:

```
h.AXES_ALL(1)=axes('parent',h.fig,'position',[L1 T W H]);
h.AXES_ALL(2)=axes('parent',h.fig,'position',[L2 T W H]);
h.AXES_ALL(3)=axes('parent',h.fig,'position',[L3 T W H]);
...
```

They all have the same dimensions and I'm using the for instruction to plot the data:

```
for i=1:11
           set(h.PLOT(i),'parent',h.AXES_ALL(i),'XData',x_data,'YData',y_data);            
end
```

But the problem is that the last plot (the 11th) is the one that is shown on the axes control (the 11th) and all the other axes are empty. My objective is to plot 11 curves on 11 different axes controls. They aren't located in the same position, just for the record.

THanks in advance!

Charlie

Comment: Normally you use the `plot` command, which can accept an axes handle.  I haven't seen plots created this way before.

Comment: How do you make the `h.PLOT(i)` handles?

Comment: I'm doing it this way because I need to update the plots in real time, that's why I update XDATA and YDATA. Thanks for your answer :)

Comment: Maybe the error is here. The 11 plots are linked to just one axes control, different than the array h.PLOT_ALL.


h.PLOT(1:11) = plot(h.AXES,0,0,'Marker','.','markersize',20,'LineWidth',1,'color',[0 0 1],'hitTest','on');

Comment: Yes, that's why, each `h.PLOT(i)` will have the same value (the same handle).  You need several plot commands. You were just moving the same plot from axes to axes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You said in your comment that you start with a single axes handle:

```
ha = axes;
```

And you try to create two plots with the same parent axes, but it does not work as you intended:

```
>> h.PLOT(1:2) = plot(ha,0,0)
h.PLOT =
  195.0035  195.0035
```

That just replicated the same plot series handle.  So, when you go to set the plot data and parent axes for each plot, you are just moving the plot from axes to axes, updating the data while you go.

Use the `plot` command in a loop, using the appropriate axes handle for each plot:

```
for ip=1:11,
    h.PLOT_ALL(ip) = plot(h.AXES_ALL(ip),...);
end
```

Then when you update the plot's `XData` and `YData` as you want to do, you do not have to change the parent axes.

Comment: I'm realizing that the plot command takes a LOT of time to display all the curves. Is there any way to improve this? For 10 plots the command takes more than 1 second, which is a lot for my real time application. Any suggestion?

Comment: Just run plot at the beginning as in the loop I showed and then after, update XData and YData as you had planned.  Is the update slow too?

Comment: I used the plot command at the beginning of the code, but when I want to update the XDATA and YDATA I get the same behavior. Only the LAST plot is the one that contains data and the rest are empty. This is the code I'm now using:

for i=1:1               set(h.PLOT(i),'parent',h.AXES_ALL(i),'XData',a_graficar(:,1),'YData',a_graficar(:,2));            
end

Any suggestion?

Comment: I'm confused if you have and array called `PLOT_ALL` or `PLOT` or both.  Also, you do not need the `'parent'` part anymore, just the `set(plotHandle,'XData',xx,'YData',yy)`. I verified this works.